# Css is centering buttons

Tags: css

I made have made my first CSS class, but I have got a little problem, the buttons are centered, but thats not what I want.

View: http://prntscr.com/6i30xg

I would like them so they start at the left side only. But when using `float: left;`to the .body class it will results in

View: http://prntscr.com/6i327q

But I would like that the buttons are on the edge like the homepage.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,300italic,400italic);

/* Typography
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 
{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300; 
}
h1
{ 
    font-size: 4.0rem; 
    line-height: 1.2;  
    letter-spacing: -.1rem;
}
h2 
{ 
    font-size: 3.6rem; 
    line-height: 1.25; 
    letter-spacing: -.1rem; 
}
h3 
{ 
    font-size: 3.0rem; 
    line-height: 1.3;  
    letter-spacing: -.1rem; 
}
h4 
{ 
    font-size: 2.4rem; 
    line-height: 1.35; 
    letter-spacing: -.08rem; 
}
h5 
{ 
    font-size: 1.8rem; 
    line-height: 1.5;  
    letter-spacing: -.05rem; 
}
h6 
{ 
    font-size: 1.5rem; 
    line-height: 1.6; 
    letter-spacing: 0; 
}

p 
{
    margin-top: 0; 
}
/* Buttons
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.btn
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 38px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 38px;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn
/* Form
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

/* Programming :D
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
code {
    padding: .2rem .5rem;
    margin: 0 .2rem;
    font-size: 90%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #F1F1F1;
    border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    border-radius: 4px; 
}

pre > code
{
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    white-space: pre; 
}

/* Content
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.content
{
    border-width: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    border-radius: 28px 28px 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 120px;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.header
{
}

.header span
{
    color: #fff;
    float: left;    
    margin-left: 28px;
    margin-top: 28px;

    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.header ul
{
    color: #fff;
    float: right;   
    margin-right: 28px;
    margin-top: 28px;
}

.header ul li
{
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px; 
    border-radius: 11px;
    margin-right: 12px;
}

.header ul li a
{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.body
{
    padding-top: 148px;

}

.footer
{

}
```

Comment: Im not but I think I cannot go against it so I need to agree, How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `margin-left: auto`; and `margin-right:auto;` from your content class. OR You can replace auto with any fixed number of pixels like 10px. Setting the margins left and right to auto makes the content to align center of the page. So do not use `auto`.

You content class should look like,

```
.content
{
    border-width: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    border-radius: 28px 28px 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 120px;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin-left: <some value in pixels>;
    margin-right: <some value in pixels>;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: But if I remove that it will be weird if your screen is really small like a square?

Comment: In that case do not use auto keyword if you do not want your content to be aligned to the center of the page. Instead use some values.

Answer (score -2):

Remove `text-align: center;` from `.btn` class

Comment: text-align: center; to a .btn class will only align texts within the button. The real problem is to align buttons to the left of the body content.

Comment: I missed the .content class @KiranVarsani